# ListView with CustomAdapter giving NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I am using one `listview` to show details of places. For that i had created one `CustomAdapter` but i don't know why it is giving me `Null Pointer Exception` please help me to sort this problem.

This is my xml file.

activity_main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_hotel"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_hotelName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_hotelAddress"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:rating="2.0"
                android:stepSize="0.5" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my updated  Custom Adapter

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<Result> results) {

    // super(context, resource, results);
    this.context = context;
    Log.v("Result Data in Adapter", results.toString());
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Result result = (Result) getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
    // context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imgView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.img_hotel);
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_hotelName);
        holder.txtAddress = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_hotelAddress);
        holder.rate = (RatingBar) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        /*
         * holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         * 
         * String url = result.icon; Log.e("URL is ", url); if (url !=
         * null) { Bitmap bitmap = fetchBitmapFromCache(url); if (bitmap
         * == null) { new
         * BitmapDownloaderTask(holder.imgView).execute(url); } else {
         * holder.imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); } } else {
         * holder.imgView.setImageBitmap(null); }
         */
        holder.imgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        holder.txtName.setText(result.name);
        holder.txtAddress.setText(result.formatted_address);
        holder.rate.setRating(result.rating);
    }
    return convertView; // super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgView;
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtAddress;
    RatingBar rate;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return results.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return results.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return results.indexOf(getItem(position));
}
```

}

And here i have set the adapter to listView

```
list.setAdapter(new CustomListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.list_item, results));
```

This is my updated code upto now but it is still giving me null pointer exception.

and this is my stack strace.

```
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.th.hotelreservationsystem.MainActivity$CustomListViewAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:183)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:696)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:306)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-13 11:13:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me friends.

Comment: Firstly, never set layout_width or layout_height to wrap_content for ListView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting your viewHolder to null in the starting of getView.
You initialized it if convertView is null. But if convertView is not null, you used it directly. Don't forget viewHolder is null if convertView is not null.

```
 Add following code in the starting of else block:
```

`holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for help guys.

I got the solution and this is my updated code with comments.

3 Mistakes of my code.
Thnks to guys who helped me

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            List<Result> results) {

         super(); // 1) here i was trying to call parameterised Constructor which          
                      // was wrong.
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Result result = (Result) getItem(position);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder(); // 2) i had not instantiated View holder 
                                               //  here i did.
            holder.imgView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_hotel);
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_hotelName);
            holder.txtAddress = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_hotelAddress);
            holder.rate = (RatingBar) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();// 3) here by mistake i
   //had commited holde with other unwanted code. here removed it.
            holder.imgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            holder.txtName.setText(result.name);
            holder.txtAddress.setText(result.formatted_address);
            holder.rate.setRating(result.rating);
        }
        return convertView; // super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgView;
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtAddress;
        RatingBar rate;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return results.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return results.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return results.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `context` is null as you have not initialize it in the constructor,

try to initialize it like this

```
 public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                List<Result> results) {
            super(context, resource, results);
           this.context=context;

        }
```

And also your viewholder is null

Try to initialize your view holder

```
 holder = new viewHolder();
```

Comment: The first line in your constructor should be `super()` though

Comment: @Pragnani: Thanks For helo but as i added this line it is giving me some another error java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: @MahaveerMuttha your custom Adapter should extend the class BaseAdapter not ArrayAdapter

Comment: i.e public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter

Comment: @Pragnani: yes i did same. now its not giving any error but it is not showing anything on Activity its showing a white screen.. please help me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26037/discussion-between-pragnani-and-mahaveer-muttha)

Comment: @MahaveerMuttha make sure that you are sending data in the results array you are passing

Comment: @Pragnani: Please check the latest code. i did all the things but still it is giving me Error. I am not finding the solution please help me i am working on it sience 2 days.....

Comment: @MahaveerMuttha // super(context, resource, results); this should not be commented

Comment: and also this  * holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); should not be commented

Comment: @MahaveerMuttha I have told you to post your activity code, if it is too big than use pastebin.com

Comment: @Pragnani: thanks for help i got the solution.. and also i seen that is we extend BaseAdapter the Construcotor is only super(); without any parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You should return convertView in your getView method instead of calling:

```
return super.getView(position, convertView, parent); // replace this line by return convertView;
```

EDIT:
So full answer would be something like this:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Result>{

        Context context;

        public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                List<Result> results) {

            super(context, resource, results);
            this.context = context; // 1
            Log.v("Result Data in Adapter", results.toString());
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            ImageView imgView;
            TextView txtName;
            TextView txtAddress;
            RatingBar rate; 
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            Result result = getItem(position);
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null ){
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder(); //2
            //  holder.imgView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_hotel);
                holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_hotelName);
                holder.txtAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_hotelAddress);
                holder.rate = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

                //holder.imgView.setImageResource();
                holder.txtName.setText(result.name);
                holder.txtAddress.setText(result.formatted_address);
                holder.rate.setRating(result.rating);
            }
            return convertView; //3
        }
    }
```

Comment: @michel Z: thanks for help.. i corrected my mistakes but now its not giving me any error but it is not showing anything on my screen just a white screen appears. please help me

Comment: Z.:  I have updated my code please have a look on it, I have edited my custom adapter in code

Comment: You are calling `Result result = (Result) getItem(position);` but your `getItem()` method always returns null.

Comment: @ Michal Z. Please check the latest code. i did all the things but still it is giving me Error. I am not finding the solution please help me i am working on it sience 2 days.....

Comment: I don't know why you commented this line `holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();`. It should be uncommented. There are many tutorials on how to create ArrayAdapter, it's really simple. And LogCat can say you where exactly is an error (183 line of MainActivity class).

Answer (score 1):

@Mahaveer 
Can you please make it

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return <Size of list items>;
}
```

hope this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your `ViewHolder` to `null`, but never initializing it.

So make your `getView()` like this:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Result result = getItem(position);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null ){
            holder = new viewHolder(); //initialize it
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            ....
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }...
```